# Flutter, how to implement native admob exactly?

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies, firebase-admob

was looking at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob and while I was in the process of implementing it, I gave up due to a problem that it could not work properly in the Android/Kotlin code part

[image]

so I decided to use another package called flutter_native_admob. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_admob

But I found something really weird. Obviously, firebase_admob should have changed something in the Android code, but this new package(flutter_native_admob) didn't have to. I opened the library package dart file one by one, and saw it implemented native admob with only the flutter internal code(no android code). So I was curious and tried to follow it, and it really worked!

However, the official firebase_admob documentation did not introduce a single method of the flutter_native_admob package, which I was newly using. What is this? I'm so confused.